# Slow boot after fresh install and update

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 16.04

I have a desktop with 8 GB RAM DDR3, AMD Phenom x3 cores, Nvidia GTX 750, mechanical Seagate 1TB hard disk.

I have installed the xubuntu on /dev/sda1 and put my /home on /dev/sda6 with a swap on /dev/sda5.

After the install the system start normally and I have saved [this dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/aPfUM2Vx).

The system seems to working very fine, so, I have make all the updates and installed some apps: vlc, chrome, plank dock (and themes), numix icons, qbittorrent, dbconf-editor, gimp, inkscape, gitg, oracle java 8 and the drivers for: Nvidia 361.42 (proprietary, tested) and Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode (proprietary).

But, after the first reboot the 5 minutes to boot started to happen like in these dmesg entries:

1. [dmesg 2](http://pastebin.com/CQ7De1DY):
2. [dmesg 3](http://pastebin.com/AxfugZKV)

`systemd-analyze blame`:

```
  3.003s ModemManager.service
  2.800s dev-sda1.device
  1.944s accounts-daemon.service
  1.885s NetworkManager.service
  1.721s polkitd.service
  1.151s gpu-manager.service
  1.116s thermald.service
  1.099s grub-common.service
   950ms networking.service
   910ms avahi-daemon.service
   859ms systemd-logind.service
   846ms systemd-modules-load.service
   749ms apparmor.service
   748ms rsyslog.service
   748ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   730ms upower.service
   665ms lightdm.service
   652ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37e8a91c\x2db5e1\x2d4bf5\x2d89dc\x2dea5b80f17596.service
   627ms plymouth-start.service
   548ms lm-sensors.service
   532ms resolvconf.service
   532ms systemd-journald.service
   499ms systemd-udevd.service
   479ms apport.service
   472ms irqbalance.service
   441ms ufw.service
   405ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   403ms dev-hugepages.mount
   403ms dev-mqueue.mount
   356ms pppd-dns.service
   260ms ondemand.service
   258ms console-setup.service
   238ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   205ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   164ms udisks2.service
   161ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2377c5fa\x2d42c4\x2d462e\x2dad91\x2d7e3f285cff90.swap
   102ms kmod-static-nodes.service
    98ms systemd-update-utmp.service
    96ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
    89ms systemd-timesyncd.service
    84ms systemd-sysctl.service
    77ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
    61ms hddtemp.service
    58ms speech-dispatcher.service
    55ms systemd-random-seed.service
    55ms systemd-journal-flush.service
    39ms systemd-remount-fs.service
    38ms rc-local.service
    36ms rtkit-daemon.service
    31ms plymouth-read-write.service
    23ms user@1000.service
    22ms home.mount
    18ms alsa-restore.service
    12ms snapd.socket
     5ms ureadahead-stop.service
     5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @10.041s
└─multi-user.target @10.041s
  └─ModemManager.service @7.038s +3.003s
    └─basic.target @7.037s
      └─sockets.target @7.037s
        └─snapd.socket @7.018s +12ms
          └─sysinit.target @7.018s
            └─apparmor.service @6.251s +749ms
              └─local-fs.target @6.249s
                └─home.mount @6.225s +22ms
                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37e8a91c\x2db5e1\x2d4bf5\x2d89dc\x2dea5b80f17596.service @5.502s +652ms
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37e8a91c\x2db5e1\x2d4bf5\x2d89dc\x2dea5b80f17596.device @5.481s
ramon@saturn:~$
```

After the boot the OS work like a charm without any problem.

So, I really don't know what I have to do to solve that 5+ minutes of boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing apparmour and see if that helps. Could also do with the fact you updated the microcode using AMD's proprietary driver, I wouldn't recommend doing such a thing unless you're having hardware stability issues.

I would remove each thing you added since the fresh intall, and reboot after every one and see if you can catch the culprit that way.

Comment: I did not make nothing and the problem goes away. http://pastebin.com/rdDtfYDL